# Disable email confirmation for super user in django allauth

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for registering user into my django application. Here the super user can log in into the application (not the default django admin panel) and can do certain operations

How can I disable email authentication if someone log in using super user credentials?